# How to change the name of PayPal Rest API App name

Tags: woocommerce, paypal

In PayPal developer, under "REST API apps", I have several apps, some of which were created automatically, thus having a fixed name. I tried to change the name like below, but it seems the inital name won't be replaced.

[image]

Is there any way, I might not see, to change this name? This would help in having a better overview of all my REST API apps.

PS: I don't know if this is helpful, but the apps are created through the PayPal Payments Plugin by Woocommerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to change the name on the preceding page's list, only the second "Display Name" field when you actually open the app. Seems to have been an oversight when this was created, but most people don't have more than a handful of apps.